# как получить склеить в строку значения перекрестной таблицы?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Я могу вернуть значения в виде строки так

```
SELECT Column1 + ', ' + Column2 + ..............
FROM <anything>
```

но что, если я не знаю сколько будет столбцов? Например, если это перекрестная таблица, у которой задан источник столбцов?

Comment: Такой вариант. 
Сначала результат сохранить во вспомогательной таблице (select * into). Затем динамически строить запрос, получая данные из information_schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Динамический SQL, список столбцов берём их представления sys.columns:

```
--Создаём табличку
IF OBJECT_ID('TempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TempTable;
GO
CREATE TABLE TempTable (
  column1 VARCHAR(50),
  column2 INT,
  column3 DATETIME
)
GO
--Наполняем данными
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT N+1 FROM CTE WHERE N<10
)
INSERT TempTable
SELECT 'STR No ' + CAST(N AS VARCHAR(11)), N, DATEADD(DD, N, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
FROM CTE
GO
--Создаём текст запроса из системного представления sys.columns
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = (
  SELECT 'SELECT ' + STUFF((
    SELECT '+'', ''+' + 'CAST([' + name + '] AS VARCHAR(max))'
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('TempTable', 'U')
    ORDER BY column_id FOR XML PATH('')
  ),1,6,'') + '[STR] FROM TempTable'
)
SELECT @sql;
--Сгенерированный текст запроса
/*
SELECT CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(max))+', '+CAST([column2] AS VARCHAR(max))+', '+CAST([column3] AS VARCHAR(max))[STR] FROM TempTable
*/
--Запускаем
EXEC(@sql)
--Результат выполнения запроса
/*
STR
STR No 1, 1, окт 25 2016 12:00AM
STR No 2, 2, окт 26 2016 12:00AM
STR No 3, 3, окт 27 2016 12:00AM
STR No 4, 4, окт 28 2016 12:00AM
STR No 5, 5, окт 29 2016 12:00AM
STR No 6, 6, окт 30 2016 12:00AM
STR No 7, 7, окт 31 2016 12:00AM
STR No 8, 8, ноя  1 2016 12:00AM
STR No 9, 9, ноя  2 2016 12:00AM
STR No 10, 10, ноя  3 2016 12:00AM
*/
```

**UPD** Как правильно подсказал msi, если данные берутся не из таблицы, а из произвольного запроса, то можно поместить всё во временную таблицу. Т.е. что-то вроде

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTable;
GO
SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM <Anything>
```

Далее всё то же самое.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = (
  SELECT 'SELECT ' + STUFF((
    SELECT '+'', ''+' + 'CAST([' + name + '] AS VARCHAR(max))'
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable', 'U')
    ORDER BY column_id FOR XML PATH('')
  ),1,6,'') + '[STR] FROM #TempTable'
)
SELECT @sql;
--Сгенерированный текст запроса
/*
SELECT CAST([column1] AS VARCHAR(max))+', '+CAST([column2] AS VARCHAR(max))+', '+CAST([column3] AS VARCHAR(max))[STR] FROM #TempTable
*/
--Запускаем
EXEC(@sql)
```